# How to put a JSON string (with multiple objects in it) into a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this JSON with multiple objects and this JSON string might come with more data/objects than 3. So, whatever the information is, I need to create an array of objects.

```
[ {"endDate":"2017-04-18","nrC":2,"type":"CO","dataD":"2017-04-19","startDate":"2017-04-16"},  
  {"endDate":"2017-04-27","nrC":4,"type":"CP","dataD":"2017-04-23","startDate":"2017-03-26"},  
  {"endDate":"2017-04-27","nrC":7,"type":"CA","dataD":"2017-04-23","startDate":"2017-04-26"}
]
```

```js
var USER_DAYS = {};

for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){   
    var USER_DAYS = [  
      {
          id: json[i].nrC,
          date: json[i].dataD,
          title: json[i].type,
          start: new Date(json[i].startDate),
          end: new Date(json[i].endDate),
          allDay: true
      },            
    ];

    console.log(i); // prints 1,2,3
}

console.log(USER_DAYS) //prints the last object from that json.
```

In that JavaScript variable must be an array with *n* objects, and when I try to print it, it should print 3 Objects instead of 1 Object. Right now my console shows only one, the last one.

I need the `USER_DAYS` variable to contain all objects from that JSON.

Comment: JSON is a way to print javascript objects as strings. What you are working with isnt json it is just normal javascript objects.

Comment: The question is not very clear... Are you already parsing the JSON to Javascript object? Do you want to only convert it to object or do you need to typecast whatever there is inside?

Comment: Also you only get the last object because you are reassigning the variable. You should use `USER_DAYS.push([ /* the code here */ ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you're not just overwriting your variable every iteration
e.g.

```
USER_DAYS[i]   = {
                   id: json[i].nrC,
                   date: json[i].dataD,
                   title: json[i].type,
                   start: new Date(json[i].startDate),
                   end: new Date(json[i].endDate),
                   allDay: true
                 }
```

And ensure that you define your Array as an Array preceding your `for` statement

So this becomes

```js
var json = [{
    "endDate": "2017-04-18",
    "nrC": 2,
    "type": "CO",
    "dataD": "2017-04-19",
    "startDate": "2017-04-16"
  },
  {
    "endDate": "2017-04-27",
    "nrC": 4,
    "type": "CP",
    "dataD": "2017-04-23",
    "startDate": "2017-03-26"
  },
  {
    "endDate": "2017-04-27",
    "nrC": 7,
    "type": "CA",
    "dataD": "2017-04-23",
    "startDate": "2017-04-26"
  }
];

var USER_DAYS = [];

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

  USER_DAYS[i] = {
    id: json[i].nrC,
    date: json[i].dataD,
    title: json[i].type,
    start: new Date(json[i].startDate),
    end: new Date(json[i].endDate),
    allDay: true
  };

  console.log(i); // prints 1,2,3
}

console.log(USER_DAYS) //prints the Array we generated
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time you go around the loop, you create a new array and discard whatever you had before.

Create the array **outside** the loop.

Push a new object into it each time you go around it.

```
// ALL CAPS is a convention used for constants. You don't have a constant. Don't use ALL CAPS
var user_days = []; // Create your array here
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  // _day_ singular. You're creating a single object here!
  // There's no `[]` here. That's outside the loop
  var user_day = {
    id: json[i].nrC,
    date: json[i].dataD,
    title: json[i].type,
    start: new Date(json[i].startDate),
    end: new Date(json[i].endDate),
    allDay: true
  };

  // Now put that object on the array you have already
  user_days.push(user_day);
}
console.log(user_days);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your JSON string with `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse('[ {"endDate":"2017-04-18","nrC":2,"type":"CO","dataD":"2017-04-19","startDate":"2017-04-16"},{"endDate":"2017-04-27","nrC":4,"type":"CP","dataD":"2017-04-23","startDate":"2017-03-26"},{"endDate":"2017-04-27","nrC":7,"type":"CA","dataD":"2017-04-23","startDate":"2017-04-26"} ]')
```

Comment: worked for my specific case